# Operator of weak type (1,1), but not of strong type (1,1)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I've seen the following claim in the book by Werner, Funktionalanalysis, and don't know how to proof the following claim: 
Let the operator $T$ be defined on $L^1[0,1]$ by
$$(Tf)(s) = \frac{1}{s} \int_0^s f(t) dt $$

Show that this operator is of weak type (1,1), but not of strong type (1,1).
I've managed to proof that it is not of the strong type, but I'm having trouble showing the weak type inequality. Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

For $a>0$ we have $$|\{x\,:|(Tf)(x)|\ge a\}|\le\left |\left \{x\,:\int\limits_0^x|f(t)|\,dt\ge ax\right \} \right |\le |\{x\,:\, \|f\|_1\ge ax\}|\le {\|f\|_1\over a}$$ Thus $$\sup_a\,a|\{x\,:|(Tf)(x)|\ge a\}|\le\|f\|_1$$ i.e. $\|Tf\|_{1,\infty}\le \|f\|_1.$